# Strange artifact on baked normal

Tags: normal-map, artifacts

I am trying to bake a normal map from a hi poly to a low poly model. Everything seems right but there are two strange artifacts that I have no idea where they come from.

One of them is right below the face, the otherone is at the middle right of the map.

On close inspection, both artifacts look kind of similar since you can see a hand.
Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks!
[image: Strange artifact on the chin and the middle right of the image]

Comment: it's probably baking invert normals, try to fix it with a higher Ray Distance or with the Extrusion value, or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.